# How to add dictionary to array in swift

Tags: swift

How to initialize and add values to array following data

```
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => First element
            [foo] => bar
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [name] => Second element
            [foo] => bar2
        )

)
```

Comment: Arrays are delimited by `[]`. Dictionaries are also delimited by the same characters but there are colons `:` to separate the keys from the values. Try it out and post your results in the question.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

That's array which contains dictionaries, Is it what you are after?

```
let myArray = [["name": "First element", "foo": "bar"], ["name": "Second element", "foo": bar2]]
```

// Edited add items in loop:

```
var myArray = [[String: String]]()
for i in 0..<10 {

    let dict = ["name": "Item\(i)", "foo": "bar\(i)"]
    myArray.append(dict)
}
print("\(myArray)")
```

Comment: Yes but that will be done in loop so I can't create whole array at once, and I have to initialize it first

Comment: Thank you i had double brackets missing :)